# How to display the images in android emulator in horizonatl view?

Tags: android, image

How to display the images in android emulator in horizonatal view?

Comment: well, how abt explaining it further more. I cant understand it.

Comment: how to display the sdcard images in horizonatal view in android emulator?

Comment: i want to display the images from sdcard folder in horizonatl view

Comment: r u asking abt lanscape mode here?

Comment: yes.about landscape mode

Comment: You can search how to design a layout for landscape mode. It is so simple. There are plenty of examples available.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-F11 or Ctrl-F12 toggles the emulator between portrait and landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="250dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mRlayoutPopImages">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/mTxtViewPopularImages"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="What's populars"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:textStyle="bold" />
        <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mHoScView" android:layout_below="@+id/mTxtViewPopularImages">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mLlayoutPopImages" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Put Below Code in Your Java File:-

```
ImageView mImgview;
int[] mImageArray = { R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.sunset,
                R.drawable.water, R.drawable.winter,
                R.drawable.blue };
LinearLayout mLlayoutPopImages;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
```

Write Following Code in onCreate Method:-

```
mLlayoutPopImages = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mLlayoutPopImages);
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(72, 72);
params.leftMargin=10;
params.rightMargin=10;
for (int i = 0; i < mImageArray.length; i++) {
     mImgview = new ImageView(this);
     mImgview.setLayoutParams(params);
     mImgview.setImageResource(mImageArray[i]);
     mLlayoutPopImages.addView(mImgview);
}
```